# Told new employer there's 30 days notice in current company, chief wants me to stay 45 days

Tags: new-job, notice-period

One company just presented me an offer letter. In the interview, I told them there's policy of 30 days of pre-notice in current company. Now, they are asking me to give confirmation on the date.

I talked with chief of present company about the resignation and he wants me to stay for 45 days to complete documentation of what I have done and for handover.

What would be a wise way to proceed?

Comment: A location would be helpful.  In the US, there are several ways to handle this.  If you're in India, (from what I've learned here) things could be quite difficult.

Comment: The only way to proceed is to make up your mind what you want. According to your information, it's your decision. We cannot make that for you.

Comment: Have you talked about this to your current boss ? Or to your soon-to-be company ?

Comment: Does the chief think it will take 15 additional days to complete documentation? Or are there other tasks your chief needs you to handle?

Comment: @sh5164 yes. current boss says 45 days as I already said and have told me to talk with soon-to-be company about this way.

Comment: @mcknz Should not talk that long but I currently am the only one who is on the job title. So, he might have guessed or don't know if he wants me to stay till month end to make financially easy.

Comment: If possible, agree on a last day that you, your current employer and future employer all find acceptable. Say e.g. "let's agree my last day will be 25 August" rather than agreeing to a number of days.

Comment: @Brandin how does company which offered takes the joining date be 1+ month? is it normal? don't know. its my first shift.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere should I not have told that this agreement with current company? What would be your suggestion to handle this que?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I had to say a round-up number of days and said 30. but also yes, its written in my current contract.

Comment: @HungryMind  As it is relevant to both this and your other question, what country are you working in?

Comment: @Myles inside south asia.

Comment: @HungryMind Customs vary some across South Asia and laws vary radically.  Are we talking about India?  This is important as the "relieving" process in India isn't common outside of it.

Comment: @HungryMind It depends on your new company. If they can wait, and you want to give your current company a few more days, then you can do that. Just agree on a concrete date to leave, agree on a concrete date to start with your new company, and it should be fine.

Comment: Questions asking us to make a decision for you like this are off topic.  What is it you would like to do and why are you having problems doing that?

Answer (score 8):

> I talked with chief of present company about the resignation and he
>   wants me to stay for 45 days to complete documentation of what I have
>   done and for handover.
>
> What would be wise way to proceed?

If your contract actually specifies 30 days, then your chief is asking you to stick around an additional 15 days for some reason. You are not obligated to do so.

If you want to stay that long, then go to your new company and indicate what your current chief is asking and tell them that you feel obligated to accommodate them (only if that's the truth - don't lie). Most likely your new company will understand.

If you don't want to stay that long, then tell your current chief that unfortunately, your new company wants you within 30 days as specified in your contract (only if that's the truth). Indicate that you will work hard in the month remaining to complete and handover whatever documentation is needed.

Then follow through. Work hard until your last day, whenever that is.

Comment: `only if that's the truth - don't lie` save your 'breath'. Look at OP's previous question.  :)

Comment: Perhaps you could better explain why lieing is not advised?

Answer (score 5):

You'd have to check your contract, and then you need to give the notice that you are required by law and by your contract. If you are required to give (only) 30 days notice and your boss wants 45, that's just tough for your boss. If you are required to give 45 notice, then you'll have to talk to the new company.